# Connect to NAS works fine w admin but not w other users

Tags: networking, ssh, network-shares

Hi I need your support how to allow different users to access my NAS remotely via WINscp or Putty. Problem is that today only user=admin is able to connect via WINscp or Putty. Loggin in w the other users via WINscp or Putty leads to "access denied". 
Some information what I did so far: 
The other users were created by user=admin via the NAS' own logon screen (the one that pops up at https:IP..etc). As admin, I also created several folders and gave each user specific access rights to those folders. 
This works as long as each user logs on to the NAS via the NAS' logon screen.  However, if the users want to access the NAS via WINscp or Putty, access is denied (except for user=admin).

My NAS: Zyxel NAS520, firmware V5.21(AASZ.0), up-to-date

On my NAS: OpenSSH 6.7, File transfer protocol SFTP-3, Cryptographic protocol SSH-2.

In WINscp this is what I see:

under the /home/ folder I can see one folder per user (and some extra folders), access rights are as follows (Jos is one of the users that I created): home/Jos; rwxr-srx; owner=Jos

under the /i-data/.../ folder I can see all the folders that I created myself, access rights are as follows: i-data/.../Foto (Jos); rwxrwsrwx;   owner=admin

I hope things are more clear now. If not, please reply and I will try to upload some pictures...and answer your additional questions.

Comment: Please edit the question with the vendor of the NAS, and the software that you used to configure it.  If you can include a screenshot of the "standard NAS Windows software" that will demonstrate to us what you are seeing.

Comment: I will try to upload some screenshots of the WINSCP folder structure too. Give me some time...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which brand/model of NAS drive you have. I had a very similar set of symptoms a while back on my Synology. I toiled for days trying to figure what was wrong with Windows, then I realized the NAS itself needed a firmware upgrade. After that, perfect.

Comment: The NAS is a Zyxel NAS520. The software I called "standard NAS Windows software" is the software you use to configure the (Zyxel) NAS, not sure how to call it, but here a link ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/NAS520/application_note/NAS520_1.0.0.pdf

Comment: Realizing I was very brief insharing details of my NAS, so here some more. On my NAS (Zyxel config software) I enabled SSH, the NAS uses file transfer protocol SFTP-3, Cryptographic protocol SSH-2, OpenSSH_6.7.